# SumProduct multiple criteria with text

Tags: arrays, excel, product, sumifs, sumproduct

[image: SumProduct]

I have a bank register on the left.  I want a code on the right to tell me sum all the times the description "Rent" is paid in that month.  I've tried index, sumproduct and sumif.  I can't find the correct way to have it search by month, year and text.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what format your tables are in.

`SUMIFS` is the easiest solution but it will only work if the bank register uses the Excel date format. It gets a little complicated if those dates are formatted as text.

Building a `SUMIFS` formula begins with the SUM RANGE.  This is a welcome change away from the backwards construction and wrongly named `SUMIF` (looks more like an `IFSUM` if you ask me)

```
=SUMIFS(SUM RANGE, CRITERIA 1 RANGE, CRITERIA 1, CRITERIA 2 RANGE, CRITERIA 2, CRITERIA 3 RANGE, CRITERIA 3...)
```

Using your example:

- `SUM RANGE`, the 'Debit' column of the bank register (BankRegisterDebitRange)
- `CRITERIA 1 RANGE`, the 'Description' column of the bank register (BankRegisterDescriptionRange)
- `Criteria 1`, the string "Rent"
- `Criteria 2 Range`, the 'Date' column of the bank register (BankRegisterDateRange)
- `Criteria 2`, this formula string `">="&EOMONTH(RentTableDate,-1)+1`
- `Criteria 3 Range`, the 'Date' column of the bank register (BankRegisterDateRange)
- `Critera 3`, this formula string `"<="&EOMONTH(RentTableDate,0)`

Putting it together:

```
=SUMIFS(BankRegisterDebitRange, BankRegisterDescriptionRange, "Rent", BankRegisterDateRange, "=>"&EOMONTH(RentTableDate, -1)+1, BankRegisterDateRange, "<="&EOMONTH(RentTableDate, 0))
```

If your data is fornatted as text then you need to decide if you want to use helper column or not or if you want a single formula.  A helper column may be desirable if you want to use `SUMIFS` or perform additional analysis with simple formulas.  A different array based formula may be desirable if you don't want a helper column, for example `SUMPRODUCT` or `SUM`.

There's already great answer showing how to use `SUMPRODUCT` so here is an example of how to build an array formula with `SUM` when your data is fornatted as text.

```
=SUM((BankRegisterDebitRange)*(BankRegisterDescriptionRange="Rent")*(DATEVALUE(BankRegisterDateRange)=>(EOMONTH(RentTableDate,-1)+1))*(DATEVALUE(BankRegisterDateRange)<=MONTH(RentTableDate,0)))
```

**This is a true array formula and must be entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter**

I was surprised by some of my results during testing.  Mainly how Excel was still treating text as dates in some cases but not others.  For example, `DATEVALUE` was needed on the bank register side but that wasn't the situation with the rent table because `EOMONTH` worked just fine without it. I believe it is related to another odd behavior: when I create a text formatted cell in `A1` and then enter a date, regardless if it is preceded by an apostrophe or not, then if I enter `=A1+1` in any other cell, that cell becomes formatted as text and displays Excel's numerical value of the day after the date in `A1`.  What I expected was a `#Value!` error.  I suspect this is what keeps `EOMONTH` from bonking and the mysterious nature of arrays somehow preventing that behavior from carrying over to `SUMIFS`... but I really do not know why this is happening.

Comment: quite an interesting topic to look at. I have shared some of my test results in my solution as well :) I guess the link between date value and numerical value is the reason behind but I totally did not expect excel to read `mmm (spaces) yyyy (spaces)` as a real date.

Comment: @Terry W that's two of us!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution]

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **BankDate** being the date column in your bank register table;
- **Desc** being the description column in your bank register table;
- **Dr** being the debit column in your bank register table.

If the look up date are `text`, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Desc="Rent")*(TEXT(BankDate,"mmm yyyy")=G2)*Dr)
```

If the look up date are `date`, you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Desc="Rent")*(TEXT(BankDate,"mmm yyyy")=TEXT(G4,"mmm yyyy"))*Dr)
```

Change `G2` or `G4` in the above formulas to suit your actual case.

> The logic is to use **TEXT** function to convert the `BankDate` into the same format as your look up date, and then use **SUMPRODUCT** function to return the rent by month.

Ps. using **SUMPRODUCT** may be an overkill, as **SUMIFS** suggested by @ProfoundlyOblivious is actually faster in excel calculation.

Ps2. as pointed out by @ProfoundlyOblivious, there is an interesting behavior in Excel in terms of treating text date as 'real' date in certain scenarios. Although it may not be relevant to the question of this post, I'd like to share some of my test results here for anyone interested:

[image: tests]

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious sorry I should have tested **EOMONTH** function before commenting that it will not work if the look up date is **text**. It is interesting to notice that this function actually works even if the look up date is in the following forms `mmm yyyy         (spaces) ` with several spaces at the end, or `mmm              (spaces) yyyy` with several spaces in between, but it will not work if there is any space in the front of the string. Then yes you are right about there is no need for a helper column :) I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: No worries at all.  This one threw me for a loop too.  I have a new theory regarding Excel's crazy format antics. You may be familiar with this quote: ["If you think you understand quantum mechanics, you don't understand quantum mechanics."](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Richard_Feynman)... Feynman was really talking about data formats in Excel.  Though, in retrospect, if he was, then that means Excel is the world's first quantum supercomputer and Microsoft has been hiding it for decades.  But then again, what better way to hide quantum supremacy than by releasing shoddy software?  Hrmm